# Bootstrap select not overflowing on auto height div

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-select

I am working on [this demo](https://www.codeply.com/go/mh1nECokbp). Why am I not able to display/overflow the `.drop-down`out of the `.item` box? I have to leave the height of the `.item` auto but not able to enable overflow visible on it.

```css
.item{
    background:khaki;
    display: run-in;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    overflow: visible !important;
    padding-top:20px;
    padding-bottom:20px;
    }
    .dropdown-menu {
        z-index: 999999999999999999999999;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Bootsrap Select -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/css/bootstrap-select.css" >
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>


<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="item active">
            <select class="selectpicker" data-width="100%">
                <option>Select</option>
                <option>0.05</option>
                <option>0.05</option>
                <option>0.05</option>
                <option>0.15</option>
                <option>0.1</option>
                <option>0.05</option>
                <option>0.05</option>
                <option>0.05</option>
                <option>0.15</option>
            </select>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use overflow:visible in the carousel-inner.You list will display. See code below

.carousel-inner{overflow:visible !important}